# my RN app crash when I upload an invalid QR CODE Image

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, qr-code

I am having a qrcode scanner module in a react native application, & when I upload a QR Code Image, it works fine, but once I upload a random image, my application crash.

Here is the code for my native module

```
package org.myapplication;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScanner;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScannerOptions;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScanning;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by lewin on 2018/3/14,
 * Updated by stefanmajiros on 2021/6/15
 */

public class QRScanReader extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule  {

    public QRScanReader(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "QRScanReader";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void readerQR(String fileUrl, final Promise promise ) {
        // ML Vision : https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android#java
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(fileUrl);
            InputImage image = InputImage.fromFilePath(this.getReactApplicationContext(), uri);
            BarcodeScannerOptions options = new BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
                    .setBarcodeFormats(
                            Barcode.FORMAT_AZTEC,
                            Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE
                    )
                    .build();
            final BarcodeScanner scanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(options);
            Task<List<Barcode>> result = scanner.process(image)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Barcode>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(List<Barcode> barcodes) {
                            Log.d("OK", " " +  barcodes.toString());
                            List<String> rawValues = new LinkedList<>();
                            for (Barcode barcode: barcodes) {
                                String rawValue = barcode.getRawValue();
                                rawValues.add(rawValue);
                            }
                            scanner.close();
                            promise.resolve(rawValues.get(0));

                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.d("NOT_OK", "" +  e.getMessage());
                            scanner.close();
                            promise.reject("NOT_OK", e.getMessage());

                        }
                    });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I import my native module like this :

```
const { QRScanReader } = NativeModules;
return QRScanReader.readerQR(fileUrl);
```

and use it :

```
const openPhoto = () => {
        const options = {
            width: 800,
            height: 800,
            cropping: true,
            mediaType: 'photo',
            hideBottomControls: true,
            enableRotationGesture: true,
            includeBase64: true,
            compressImageQuality: 0.8,
        };
        ImagePicker.openPicker(options).then(d => {
            try {
                QRreader(d.path)
                .then(x => {
                    onSuccess(x);
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log('e', e)
                });
            } catch (err) {
                onFail(err);
                
            }
        });
    };
```

I want to control the behavior and show a pop-up or something if a user enters some random pictures, other than a valid(QR code) Image. I want to execute the onFail function

EDIT:
After debugging with Android Studio, I noticed that even when I upload an invalid qrcode image (for example a random screenshot), it enters my onSuccess listener (addOnSuccessListener) and here is the stack trace of the error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: org.myapplication, PID: 27755
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
> at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:555)
> at java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:476)
> at org.myapplication.QRScanReader$2.onSuccess(QRScanReader.java:65)
> at org.myapplication.QRScanReader$2.onSuccess(QRScanReader.java:55)
> at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)

Comment: A Crash usually means there is a stack trace printed e.g. on `logcat`. Without a stack trace identifying the crash reason is more complicated as necessary. So please edit your question and include the stack trace.

Comment: @Robert As I am working with vs code I still didn't figure a way to debug the java -native module code. I am still working it out with Android Studio. So, for now, I still don't have a stack trace. Once I have, I will update the question

Comment: @Robert I updated my post with the stack trace, and I found the reason for the crash and corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Robert suggested to add the stack trace, I needed to debug but it wasn't working for me before.
So, once I figured out how to debug my native module/java code I found out that when I upload a random picture the barcodes : parameter (List) is empty. So when resolving the promise, the 'rawValues.get(0)' a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException unhandled exception arises.
So in my case, I resolved this issue by testing if the parameter barcodes is empty:

```
if(barcodes.isEmpty()) {
    Log.d("NOT OK", "  INVALID QR CODE IMAGE" );
    scanner.close();
    promise.resolve("ERROR : INVALID QR CODE IMAGE");
} else {
    List<String> rawValues = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Barcode barcode : barcodes) {
        String rawValue = barcode.getRawValue();
        rawValues.add(rawValue);
    }
    Log.d("OK", " " + rawValues);
    scanner.close();
    promise.resolve(rawValues.get(0));
}
```

If there is any better solution, I would be grateful!